# Pegar dados do banco por sessão com Django

Tags: python, django

Inicio minha sessão

```
request.session['username'] = 'usuario'
request.session['password'] = 'senha'
```

Aqui é o seguinte, se existir a sessão *username*, *password* e não existir a sessão *challenge*, eu gostaria que pegasse os dados do banco pelo nome de usuário que está com a sessão aberta. (meu caso o nome da sessão é usuário mesmo)

```
def gender(request):
  if request.session.get('username') and request.session.get('password') and not request.session.get('challenge'):
    a = User.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'gender/gender.html', {'a': a})
  return redirect('home')
```

Resumindo o código acima, se o gender for igual a = 1 redireciona pra home se for 0 escolha.

Mas está pegando os dados de todos do banco de dados, gostaria só da minha sessão

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi com o seguinte:

Com a sessão startada:

```
request.session['username'] = 'Guilherme'
request.session['password'] = '1234567'
```

Faço contato com meu *model*, peço pra ele que busque tudo que for do nome da sessão, no caso, Guilherme:

```
getAllData = User.objects.get(username=request.session['username'])
```

Com isso, apenas verifico:

```
if getAllData.gender == 1 or getAllData.gender == 2:
   return redirect('home')
```

Se meu `gender` for 1 ou 2 ele redireciona para home.

Isso é tudo.